# Subclass Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I seem to be unable to subclass Crashlytics with Swift. My Mock object looks like this:

```
class MockCrashlytics: Crashlytics {
    var newValue: AnyObject?
    var newKey: String?

    override func setObjectValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
        newValue = value
        newKey = key
    }
}
```

However, if I instantiate this class, I get the superclass.

Debugger example:

```
po MockCrashlytics()
<Crashlytics: 0x7fff4188cb30>
```

I would expect:

```
po MockCrashlytics()
<MockCrashlytics: 0x7fff4188cb30>
```

When I try to access `newValue` or `newKey` I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than this

Comment: @tbondwilkinson: That's all there is to it though. I am trying to subclass Crashlytics so I can mock it in my unit-test. I want to assert that my class has called the setObjectValue.ForKey method of Crashlytics. Or what else do you need?

Comment: How are you accessing `newValue` and `newKey`?  Through the debugger?

Comment: Debugger and normally in my unit test, for assertion. Example: assertThat(mockCrashlytics.newKey, equalTo("something")) .. im using hamcrest.

Comment: This behaviour is puzzling. Other mocks in the same UnitTest work just fine.

Comment: I replicated it.  This is really strange... I think it has something to do with extending an Objective-c class, but I've done that before without trouble...

Comment: It might have something to do with this: (initializers not being inherited) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783584/Subclassing-Objective-C-classes-in-Swift-and-the-p

Comment: @tbondwilkinson: Thanks, I think this might be a good clue. I will research restrictions in subclassing. I am also confused that I cannot override sharedInstanceI() in my mock...

Comment: @tbondwilkinson: I asked Crashlytics, they say it's probably one of their safety mechanisms that prevents tampering with the class. They say I should probably use a wrapper class and not a Crashlytics mock. (just FYI, I consider this issue as resolved. Thx.)

Comment: not possible to subclass crashlaytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Crashlytics is not supposed to be subclassed. It seems that some mechanism is preventing proper subclassing, so developers don't tamper with their code.

This information was given by the helpdesk of Crashlytics/Fabric.io.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class that holds a field variable of type Crashlytics.  Add your variables of newValue and newKey to the wrapper class.

```
class crashWrapper {

    var newValue: AnyObject?
    var newKey: String?
    //or whatever the correct way to init Crashlytics is
    var crashlytics = Crashlytics()

    override func setObjectValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
        newValue = value
        newKey = key
    }

}
```